# System.ArgumentException: The chip number 0 is invalid or is not enabled

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi

I am a beginner of Raspberry PI for GPIO.

I am trying a tutorial to test the PWM.

Here is the code of the tutorial:

```
PwmChannel pwmch = PwmChannel.Create(0, 0, 100, 0.0);        
pwmch.Start();
int x = 5;
while (x-- > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pwmch.DutyCycle = i * 0.01d;
        Thread.Sleep(20);
    }
    for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--)
    {
        pwmch.DutyCycle = i * 0.01d;
        Thread.Sleep(20);
    }
}
pwmch.Stop();
pwmch.Dispose();
```

After the program ran, putty report this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: The chip number 0 is invalid or is not enabled.
```

I am not sure but it seems I haven't enabled some settings for it.

In addition, I have followed the tutorial to change the dtoverlay like this:
cd /boot
sudo nano config.txt

change the dtoverlay from:
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
to
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d,pwn,pin=18,func=2

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

That overlay configuration is wrong for pwm, not sure where you found that. The `vc4-fkms-v3d` overlay is for the graphics driver and has nothing to do with pwm.

Instead of changing that line, add this line to the end of the file:

```
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,pin=12,pin2=13,func=4,func2=4
```

And then reboot. That will use pins 12 and 13, you can also use 18 and 19, but then the func values need to be different. The valid values are:

```
Name:   pwm-2chan
Info:   Configures both PWM channels
        Legal pin,function combinations for each channel:
          PWM0: 12,4(Alt0) 18,2(Alt5) 40,4(Alt0)            52,5(Alt1)
          PWM1: 13,4(Alt0) 19,2(Alt5) 41,4(Alt0) 45,4(Alt0) 53,5(Alt1)
        N.B.:
```

[(Source)](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README)